# How to create a nested list by sending data from a function

Tags: javascript, list

I have the next code:

```
let dataList = [];

function filli(index, name, words){
    dataList[index] = index;
    dataList[index] = name;
    dataList[index] = words;
}

filli(0, "David", "Testing this")
filli(1, "John", "My cellphone")
console.log(dataList)
```

I get in console the next:

```
$ node attempt.js
[ 'Testing this', 'My cellphone' ]
```

And my expected output in console would be:

```
[[0, "David", "Testing this"], [1, "John", "My cellphone"]]
```

But I don´t get that in console, as you can see I was trying to get that data in my `filli` function, sending an index, name, and words but it doesn't work.

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding existing values when you do `dataList[index]= ...`. You need to add them as an array, something like this:

```
let dataList = [];

function filli(index, name, words){
    dataList[index] = [index, name, words];
}

filli(0, "David", "Testing this")
filli(1, "John", "My cellphone")
console.log(dataList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the same value:

```
let dataList = [];

function filli(index, name, words){
    dataList[index] = [] // first create new array
    dataList[index][0] = index; // then assign to proper indexes
    dataList[index][1] = name;
    dataList[index][2] = words;
}

filli(0, "David", "Testing this")
filli(1, "John", "My cellphone")
console.log(dataList)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Ideally* functions should *return* a value which your function doesn't at the moment. An alternative solution would be to add your arguments to an array and return that, and then push that result into the `dataList` array.

```js
const dataList = [];

function filli(index, name, words){
  return [index, name, words];
}

dataList.push(filli(0, 'David', 'Testing this'));
dataList.push(filli(1, 'John', 'My cellphone'));

console.log(dataList);
```